# When removing Admistrator to folder permission, user cant access the folder

Tags: windows-server-2003

I created **FolderA** and set permission for **Administrator**, **Creator Owner**, **SYSTEM** and **UserA**. I even uncheck the **Allow inheritance Permission**

**UserA** should have access to **FolderA**

**UserA** can access **FolderA** as he should.

But when I log in with another User, I can still access the **FolderA**.

However, when I remove the **Administrator**, and retain the 3 users (**Creator Owner**, **SYSTEM** and **UserA**) in the folder permissions, **UserA** cannot access **FolderA**.

Why is that? Can you help me identifying the problem?

Do I need to create a group policy for this?

Comment: You do indeed need to create a group policy.  It would actually be easier to create a group that can access it and just place `UserA` in that group.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some confusion between Security Groups and Group Policy. Security Groups are used to set security boundaries which in turn are used to determine access and control. In the case of files and folders, placing UserA in SecurityGroupA then granting SecurityGroupA NTFS/Share Permissions effectively gives those permissions to all members within the security group.

Group Policy is generally used to grant other rights and permissions to objects within Active Directory (Logon Locally, RAS Enabled, Shutdown, Restart and many hundreds of other non-filesystem related actions.

One of the things commonly missed when changing NTFS/Share permissions is that a user will almost always have to log off then log back on when you add/remove them from a security group to reflect changes in their security token.

How Access Tokens Work - 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783557(v=WS.10).aspx

Understanding User and Group Accounts - 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726978.aspx